# Variable not defined even using global python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

PYTHON
Just started working with cogs in discord.py so I was copying my code around into cogs but one thing that worked before isn't working in a cog and I cannot figure out why. Code sample below.

```py
    sverify_index=0
    sverify_msg_id=""
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == 888529033405530183 and message.author.id != 887542628063780864:
                global sverify_index, sverify_msg_id
                sverify_index += 1
                sverify_list = []
                sverify_list.append(sverify_index)
```

Currently the error I am getting is

```
line 19, in on_message
    sverify_index += 1
NameError: name 'sverify_index' is not defined
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the indentation and the existence of `self`, I think you have something like

```
class Something...:
    sverify_index=0
    sverify_msg_id=""
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
         ...
```

That will make `sverify_index` and `sverify_msg_id` class-level variables (shared by all instances of `Something...`), not global variables.

If you truly want them to be global variables, you can do

```
sverify_index = 0
sverify_msg_id = ""

class Something...:
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
         global sverify_index, sverify_msg_id
```

to make them real global variables.

Comment: Alternatively since they probably don't actually need to be global, you could qualify each reference with the name of the class.  `Something.sverify_index += 1`

Comment: @MarkRansom In all truth, they probably _should_ be true instance variables, so each instance of the cog plugin would have their own copies...

Answer (score 0):

As AKX mentioned, they are defined class-level variables currently.
In order to have them as global variables, they can be moved out of the class.

### An Alternative Approach

Since the question was not about making them global variables, but why they are not accessible when moved to a class, another solution can be to keep them as class-level variables, and then access them like `self.sverify_index` and `self.sverify_msg_id`.

So the solution will be as follows

```py
class Something(commands.Cog):
    ...

    sverify_index=0
    sverify_msg_id=""
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if (message.channel.id == 888529033405530183 and 
            message.author.id != 887542628063780864):
        
            self.sverify_index += 1
            self.sverify_list = []
            self.sverify_list.append(self.sverify_index)
```